# iCloud Status not configured on iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, icloud

I am developing an app with Xcode 5.0.2. My project configuration is base SDK iOS 7.0 and Deployment target is 6.0. I've configured iCloud and it works fine for an iOS 7 device. My problem is when I try to use iCloud in an iOS 6 device.

When I debug the app with Xcode I see this in the debug navigator --> **iCloud Report** section:

[image]

But when I debug my app on a device with iOS 6.1.3 I see this:

[image]

I've tested the app on four different devices, two with iOS 6 and two with iOS 7. Both with iOs 7 worked fine and both with iOS 6 don't connect with iCloud. All devices have iCloud configured with the same account and save docs and data enabled.

What's wrong? What can I do to make it works on iOS 6 device?

**EDIT 1:**

After a day of testing I can narrow the scope of my question. I have noticed that the "debug gauges" are only visible in Xcode when the application runs on a device with iOS 7. However, on devices with iOS 6 these are not visible.

Can anyone confirm me that this is so?
It can be configured in Xcode or in iOS 6 device?

I think that when I see that iCloud isn't configured doesn't refer to iOS 6 device, but rather it refers to Mac OS.

Anyway, leaving aside the "debug gauges" iCloud is still not working for me in iOS 6 devices.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the iOS 6 device has been configured to have an iCloud account?

Comment: iOS 6 devices have exactly the same configuration as the iOS 7 devices. They have streaming photos and other apps working properly with iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a sync problem an noticed this, I thought the problem was as Xcode said: iCloud not configured.

But really, it was latency, especially in my case, there was a lot to sync, eventually my program worked, and clearly synced between devices using iCloud.

Don't be surprised if this is a bug, after all, it's Xcode ;)